# Vector of non-static void member pointer functions with this

Tags: c++, vector, pointer-to-member

In C++17, how do you create a vector of non-static member pointer functions with `this` and subsequently call the functions?

Example.hpp

```
class Example{
    public:
        Example();

        void function1();
        void function2();
};
```

Example.cpp (psuedocode)

```
Example::Example(){
    std::vector<void (*)()> vectorOfFunctions;
    vectorOfFunctions.push_back(&this->function1);
    vectorOfFunctions.push_back(&this->function2);

    vectorOfFunctions[0]();
    vectorOfFunctions[1]();
}

void Example::Function1(){
    std::cout << "Function 1" << std::endl;
}

void Example::Function2(){
    std::cout << "Function 2" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::function` instead of pointer to members:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> vectorOfFunctions;

vectorOfFunctions.push_back(std::bind(&Example::function1, this));
vectorOfFunctions.push_back(std::bind(&Example::function2, this));
```

This allows you to generalize the vector to hold static member functions or other type of functions.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a pointer to members or would a pointer only work for a static member function?

Comment: `function1,2` are member functions, you use bind for them, for static member functions you do it directly, `vectorOfFunctions.push_back(&Example::function3)` assuming `function3` is a static member function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to member function pointer, it should be

```
std::vector<void (Example::*)()> vectorOfFunctions;
//                ^^^^^^^^^
vectorOfFunctions.push_back(&Example::function1);
vectorOfFunctions.push_back(&Example::function2);
```

And invoke them like

```
(this->*vectorOfFunctions[0])();
(this->*vectorOfFunctions[1])();
```

BTW: As a supplement to [Jans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53164640/3309790), you can also use `std::function` with [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), e.g.

```
std::vector<std::function<void ()>> vectorOfFunctions;
vectorOfFunctions.push_back([this]() { this->function1(); });
vectorOfFunctions.push_back([this]() { this->function2(); });

vectorOfFunctions[0]();
vectorOfFunctions[1]();
```